# Echo the keys of a array on a single line ? PHP

Tags: php

How to get an echo of the keys of a array, on a single line ?

```
[The] => s
[revelation] => b
[that] => z
[the] => d
[Star] => e  
[Wars] => h
```

Result :

```
<p>The revelation that the Star Wars.</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
$myArray = [
    'The' => 's',
    'revelation' => 'b',
    'that' => 'z',
    'the' => 'd',
    'Star' => 'e',
    'Wars' => 'h',
];

echo implode(' ', array_keys($myArray));
```

This basically gets an array of the keys, then implodes them with spaces.